# Xamarin forms how to fix NavBar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with Shell.NavBar, the fact is that when I open the Editor, the NavBar is not visible.

My Code Page xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Corporate_messenger.Service"
             x:Class="Corporate_messenger.Views.ChatPage" Shell.BackgroundColor="#04283C" Shell.TitleColor="White" x:Name="set_pqage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem  
            IconImageSource="audioSocket.png" 
            x:Name="VoiceRecord" 
            Clicked="VoiceRecord_Clicked">
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior 
            Command="{Binding GoBack}">
        </BackButtonBehavior>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate 
            x:Key="FromTemplate">
                <ViewCell 
                x:Name="FromUserCell" 
                IsEnabled="True"  >
                    <ViewCell.View >
                        <FlexLayout 
                            JustifyContent="Start">

                            <Frame 
                            BackgroundColor="#ECEDF1"
                            CornerRadius="14"                          
                            Padding="5,10,10,10"
                            HasShadow="false"               
                            Margin="10,10,40,0">
                                <StackLayout 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding Message}" 
                                        IsEnabled="True"                                      
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   
                                        TextColor="Black"/>
                                    <ImageButton 
                                        x:Name="LeftPlay" 
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView},Path=BindingContext.PlayAudioMessage}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  
                                        Source="{Binding Path=SourceImage,Mode=TwoWay}"                                         
                                        IsVisible="{ Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"       
                                        WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35" 
                                        CornerRadius="50" 
                                        BackgroundColor="#0986CE">
                                    </ImageButton>
                                    <Slider 
                                        x:Name="LeftSlider" 
                                        IsVisible="{Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Maximum="{Binding MaximumSlider}" 
                                        Value="{Binding ValueSlider}"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableSlider}" 
                                        MaximumTrackColor="Gray" 
                                        MinimumTrackColor="#41A9FE"                                         
                                        WidthRequest="150">
                                    </Slider>
                                    <Label   
                                        Text="{Binding Time_LstMessage}" 
                                        FontSize="11" MinimumWidthRequest="30" 
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="End" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"   
                                        TextColor="DimGray"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

            <!--Правый блок сообщений-->
            <DataTemplate 
                x:Key="ToTemplate">
                <ViewCell  
                x:Name="ToUserCell" 
                IsEnabled="True">
                    <FlexLayout 
                    JustifyContent="End" >
                        <Frame                      
                    CornerRadius="14" 
                    BackgroundColor="#CCE4FF"
                    Padding="5,10,10,10"
                    Margin="50,10,20,0"
                    HasShadow="false"      
                    IsClippedToBounds="True">
                            <StackLayout 
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label    
                                    Text="{Binding Message}" 
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsMessageVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="True" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"   
                                    TextColor="Black"/>
                                <ImageButton
                                    x:Name="RightPlay"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView},Path=BindingContext.PlayAudioMessage}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  
                                    Source="{Binding Path=SourceImage,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    IsVisible="{ Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    WidthRequest="35" 
                                    HeightRequest="35" 
                                    CornerRadius="50" 
                                    BackgroundColor="#0986CE">
                                </ImageButton>

                                <Slider 
                                    Maximum="{Binding MaximumSlider}" 
                                    Value="{Binding ValueSlider}"                                    
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableSlider}"                                    
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAuidoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    WidthRequest="150"  
                                    MaximumTrackColor="Gray" 
                                    MinimumTrackColor="#41A9FE">
                                </Slider>

                                <Label  
                                    Text="{Binding Time_LstMessage}" 
                                    FontSize="11" 
                                    MinimumWidthRequest="30" 
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="End" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"   
                                    TextColor="DimGray"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </FlexLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:ClassDataTemplateSelector
                x:Key="chatDataTemplateSelector" 
                FromTemplate="{StaticResource FromTemplate}" 
                ToTemplate="{StaticResource ToTemplate}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            
            <ListView
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" 
                RefreshCommand="{Binding UpdateList}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource chatDataTemplateSelector}"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding LastMessage}"
                Background="#04283C" 
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
                RefreshControlColor="Cyan"  
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                SeparatorColor="Transparent"  
                x:Name="MyListView" 
                HasUnevenRows="true" 
                >
            </ListView>

            <Grid 
                RowSpacing="0" 
                ColumnSpacing="0">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <!--Атрибут для написания сообщения-->
                <Editor
                    Text="{Binding Input_message}"  
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"  
                    x:Name="MessageEditor"  
                    Keyboard="Chat" 
                    TextColor="Black" 
                    Placeholder="Введите сообщение..." 
                    AutoSize="TextChanges" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0">
                </Editor>
             
                <ImageButton
                    Command="{Binding SendMessage}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    Source="send_msg.png" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                    WidthRequest="32" HeightRequest="32" 
                    x:Name="send_message"  
                  />

                <ImageButton  
                    Pressed="mic_message_Pressed" 
                    Released="mic_message_Released" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="2" 
                    Source="mic.png" 
                    Padding="0" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"  
                    WidthRequest="32" 
                    HeightRequest="32" 
                    x:Name="mic_message" 
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Go to page code:

```
async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var v = (ChatListModel)e.Item;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ChatPage(v.Id, v.Title));
}
```

Example in pictures:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izMx6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1FPm.png)

Comment: is this page contained within a NavigationPage?

Comment: @Jason, I think yes

Comment: @Jason,
I use shell for navigation

Comment: Please show code 1) shell “route” declarations, either in xaml or cs. 2) xaml or cs code line that goes to that page. gotoasync?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I added the Jump code to the page, Take a look

Comment: `I am writing an android application` Sorry, we couldn't reproduce this problem on my android device. Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this [open issue - Shell - Navigation.PushAsync - Navigation Bar ignored on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6604). In there is a comment saying the work-around for now is to set [`ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) on each page.

```
<ContentPage
    ...
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    ... >
```

OR to avoid adding that to every page, make a `BaseContentPage` class that includes those two lines, then have your pages inherit from `BaseContentPage` instead of `ContentPage`.

Comment: I am writing an android application